# Elm with webcomponents - Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: web-component, elm

**Problem summary**
I am using webcomponents in elm 0.19.1.
Goal is for the webcomponent to emit an event if the webcomponent attribute "requeststate" changes.
The event is emitted (I can see in the the logging in the webcomponent constructor), but elm is not firing the 'WebcomponentEvent' correctly.
Problem is on both windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04, firefox and chrome.
Didnot test older elm versions.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- I have the problem reproduced in this minimal repo:
  https://github.com/Derryrover/elm_webcom_bug
- Compile elm with:
  elm make src/Main.elm --output elm.js --debug
- use a webserver (for example 'serve') to host locally
- click the button 'request'. This will change the attribute 'requeststate' on the webcomponent. That in turn triggers the custom event 'created' on the webcomponent. But elm does not receive this event..

Opening the elm-debugger or clicking the 'request' button again will magically make the event fire in elm. Strange.
Also I have made the branch 'tom-experiment'. In this branch I got the event from webcomponent-click working, but only if I directly click on the webcomponent itself.

**The importance of this problem**
Why do I want to trigger an event on a webcomponent by changing an attribute?
Goal of this approach is also JavaScript interop.
For example I can now use this webcomponent to create a date-time or uuid or do some other javascript magic. This way I can work around ports completely.
A solution for this problem might settle the entire Javascript interop discussion !

**Code**

This is my Main.elm:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html
import Html.Attributes
import Html.Events
import Json.Decode

main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }

type alias Model =
    { request : Bool
    , received: Bool
    }

init : Model
init = { request = False
       , received = False 
       }


type Msg
    = Request
    | Reset
    | WebcomponentEvent


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        WebcomponentEvent ->
            { model | received = True}
        Request ->
            { model | request = True }
        Reset -> 
            { model | request = False , received = False}
        


view : Model -> Html.Html Msg
view model =
    Html.div []
        [ Html.button [Html.Events.onClick Request] [Html.text "Request"]
        , Html.div 
            [] 
            [ Html.text "requested:"
            , Html.text (if model.request then "true" else "false")
            ]
        , Html.div 
            [] 
            [ Html.text "received:"
            , Html.text (if model.received then "true" else "false")
            ]
        , Html.button [Html.Events.onClick Reset] [Html.text "Reset"]
        , Html.node "webcomponent-test" 
            [ Html.Events.on "created" (Json.Decode.succeed WebcomponentEvent) 
            , Html.Attributes.attribute "requeststate" (if model.request == True then "requested" else "idle")
            ] []
        ]
```

This is the webcomponent.js

```
class Webcomponent extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() { 
    return [
    "requeststate"
    ]; 
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch (name) {
      case  "requeststate":
        if (newValue === "requested") {
          console.log(`requested in webcomponent triggered`);
          const customEvent = new CustomEvent('created', {detail: ""});
          this.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
        }
    }
  }
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.addEventListener('created', function (e) {
      console.log("event triggered as sensed by javascript: ", e.detail, e);
    }, false, true);
    
  }
}

customElements.define('webcomponent-test', Webcomponent);
```

this is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="./webcomponent.js"></script>
    <script src="./elm.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="elm_element"></div>
    <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.init({
      node: document.getElementById('elm_element')
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was discussed on the Elm Slack. The issue ended up being a timing issue. The resolution is to change from

```js
this.dispatchEvent(customEvent)
```

to

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.dispatchEvent(customEvent))
```

in the custom element, as can be seen in this ellie https://ellie-app.com/cqGkT6xgwqKa1.

Thanks to @antew for the final solution.

Comment: Just as an additional note for anyone else who find their way here, Elm does have recommendations around how to incorporate custom web components into your Elm app: https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements.html for using browser APIs like Intl and demonstrated here. There are additional examples in the links on that page as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is another potential cause:

This `attributeChangedCallback` runs **before** the element is connected to the DOM

```
attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch (name) {
      case  "requeststate":
        if (newValue === "requested") {
          console.log(`requested in webcomponent triggered`);
          const customEvent = new CustomEvent('created', {detail: ""});
          this.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
        }
    }
  }
```

Add

```
 connectedCallback(){
    console.log("Now I am ready to emit Events");
 }
```

to verify your `dispatchEvent` doesn't run too soon.

`requestAnimationFrame` (or `setTimeout`) are workarounds to wait till the Event Loop is empty (and thus connectedCallback ran)

(I don't know your use case) You could also test for `oldValue === null` or `this.isConnected` in your `attributeChangedCallback`

Also note you probably need `bubbles:true` and `composed:true` on that CustomEvent when shadowDOM is involved.